# How to redirect on node save to fill out extra fields attached to terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities, redirection

I've added a mandatory email field to terms in a vocabulary I have called Instructor.  This field is displayed on my content type as an autocomplete term reference.  Because it is an autocomplete field, it will save new non-existing tags.  I am curious how I can redirect to a page on node  save (and subsequently term save) so that users can fill out the email fields?

Better yet, is it possible to limit autocomplete tags to existing terms, and then add a local action for "add a new instructor" where users have to fill out all fields?

Comment: It is possible to limit the autocomplete tags to existing terms if you're using cck-auto-complete module..

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I am running D7 and using core term reference field.

Comment: In that case you should specify the allowed values list by entering PHP code.

Comment: Is that redirect mandatory? why cant you use Profile module? If you can use profile module i can help you on this.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from the profile module, as it is really unnecessary, although if it would be easier to implement, then I could consider it.

The reason for the redirect is b/c I'm using the email field as described in this topic  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24038/how-can-i-link-a-text-field-to-a-user-profile-such-that-i-can-display-nodes-on-t

Comment: Youre doing some non Drupal things.

Comment: Haha yeah I kind of get that feeling.  You understand what I am trying to do right? If you have a better approach, I am open to ideas.  Even a different way of achieving a similar site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found there's a new module called Entity Connect which adds a button to entity reference fields for creating new references on the fly.  The module sends the user to the entity creation page (add term, etc) allowing you to fill out all necessary fields, then redirects back to the original node form.

This works great.  Now the only thing necessary now for my use case is to figure out how to programmatically add taxonomy terms based on the value(s) of the entity reference field.